# Trying to run bower install on an openshift app

Tags: npm, openshift, bower

i just deployed a git repo to my **Openshift** app. The game runs locally on my computer by running

```
gulp
```

Trying this on Openshift after ssh'ing

I just installed a local **bower**

```
npm install bower
```

and then tried `bower install` but get this:

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/var/lib/openshift/53dd22222e0b8cdd07d00026f/.config'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:642:18)
```

npm install works fine

#### How do I run the bower?

Also another issue is that after deploying with `app-deploy` inside my directory with `.git`, the deployed files seem to be several commits behind what I had on my computer. How do I get the latest files on there with `rhc` `app-deploy`

I can't even see the git repo on there. in `cd app-root/repo/`

Comment: possibly related to the issue reported here - https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa-bower/issues/29

Comment: @drorb thx, but seems like a big workaround

Comment: @drorb any idea about being several commits behind

Comment: sorry now idea about that

Comment: It just seems that there is too many hoops to jump through to get this free software to work

Answer (score 7):

Bower expects to be able to write some of its config files in `$HOME/.bower/` (or inside `.config`), but OpenShift does not provide write access to `$HOME`.

You can work around this issue by prepending `HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` before the `bower` command whenever you run it:

```
HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR bower
```

Comment: joël: depends on where you call the bower cli script in your code. I'd probably put it in your package.json file's "scripts" section.